# High performance Object to hashmap conversion

Tags: java, json, hashmap, gson, objectmapper

Is there a better way to convert a pojo class to hashmap without costing performance problems?

There are ObjectMapper.convertValue() and GSON.toJson conversion or simply adding alll fields to hashmap manually. Which one gives a better performance?

Comment: `"or simply adding alll fields to hashmap manually..."`: If you mean doing this statically (without using reflection), then that is likely to be your best option. But this is something you need to test/benchmark.

Comment: @ernest_k I also wanted to make sure only not null values are being passed. If i were to add a null check on each fields it again has additional cost

Comment: Do you have an actual performance problem that you're trying to address? Or is this just looking for a hypothetically "best-performing" approach?

Comment: I have currently implemented my conversion using the Objectmapper convert to Map. But since this internally uses reflections our perf team asked me to implement using GSON. I'm trying to find if there are any alternatives to GSON as well just to avoid double conversion Object to String and String to Map.

Comment: @ernest_k Trying to set like this.
`Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
  Optional.ofNullable(details.getAccountId()).ifPresent(val -> data.put("accountId", val));
  Optional.ofNullable(details.getAccountName()).ifPresent(val -> data.put("accountName", val));`

I have like more than 30 fields. Not sure if this gives a better performance.

Comment: If they don't have to substantiate their requirement, then maybe you can rely on your own tests or on published benchmarks (such as [this one](https://blog.takipi.com/the-ultimate-json-library-json-simple-vs-gson-vs-jackson-vs-json/))

Comment: @ernest_k Thanks for the info. Appreciate your help!

Comment: Creating a HashMap for each object is likely to cause performance problems. I would consider an alternative to using a HashMap if performance is important.